# InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
fileMovementRepository.GetAll()
                    .Where(fm => repository.GetAll().Select(f => f.Id).Contains(fm.FileId) && fm.TransferredById == userId)
                    .Include(f => f.User).Include(f => f.File).ThenInclude(f => f.Category)
                    .OrderByDescending(f => f.MovedOn)
                    .GroupBy(f => f.FileId)
                    .Select(f=>f.First())
                    .ToList();
```

The following error is showing on runtime

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: f.FileId,
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
EntityType: FileMovement
ValueBufferExpression:
ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
IsNullable: False

.First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)

InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: f.FileId, ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: FileMovement ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: False .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message?

Comment: Please look for the many other questions on this error. This `GroupBy` usage is not supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ToList()` before `GroupBy` and it will work as expected.

```
fileMovementRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(fm => repository.GetAll().Select(f => f.Id).Contains(fm.FileId) && fm.TransferredById == userId)
                .Include(f => f.User).Include(f => f.File).ThenInclude(f => f.Category)
                .OrderByDescending(f => f.MovedOn)
                .ToList()
                .GroupBy(f => f.FileId)
                .Select(f=>f.First())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It helped to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case and with the provided example it fails on

```
repository.GetAll().Select(f => f.Id).Contains(fm.FileId)
```

because f.Id is not nullable and fm.FileId is nullable.
I created a List<int?> for it before the query and the main query worked.

```
List<int?> repositoryIds =  repository.GetAll().Select(f => (int?)f.Id).ToList();
fileMovementRepository.GetAll()
                        .Where(fm => repositoryIds.Contains(fm.FileId) && fm.TransferredById == userId)
                        .Include(f => f.User).Include(f => f.File).ThenInclude(f => f.Category)
                        .OrderByDescending(f => f.MovedOn)
                        .GroupBy(f => f.FileId)
                        .Select(f=>f.First())
                        .ToList();
```